# Cassandra drop keyspace throws timeoutexception before specified timeout given to executeAsync

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-driver

I am getting cassandra `OperationTimedOutException` while dropping keyspace. Although I have given **60000 Milliseconds (1 minute)** `timeOut` to block until I get `Future` object from cassandra `executeAsync`. But immediately it throws `timeoutexception` **without** waiting complete 1 minute.

This is how I am removing keyspace using java -

```
List<KeyspaceMetadata> keyspaceMetadataList = cluster.getMetadata().getKeyspaces();
    for(KeyspaceMetadata ks: keyspaceMetadataList)
    {
         if (ks.getName().startsWith("system"))
         {
             continue;
         }
         try
        {
            session.executeAsync("drop keyspace " + ks.getName()).get(1000 * 60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            log.info("Dropped Keyspace: " + ks.getName());
        }
        catch( InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e )
        {
            log.error("Something went wrong: " + e);
        }

    }
```

You can see the below-given line, where I forcefully telling the call to wait at least 60 seconds, but even before that, I got `TimeOutException`.

```
session.executeAsync("drop keyspace " + ks.getName()).get(1000 * 60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I am not sure if this is the right way for increasing timeout programmatically. please let me know if any other good way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better not to do multiple modifications in the same time (like you're doing via `executeAsync`).  When you're modifying schema in the distributed system, schema changes should settle, and all nodes should have agreement between them.

I suggest to modify your code to execute commands via `session.execute` instead of async version.  And check for schema agreement when all operations are done - there is a corresponding method in the `Metadata` class.

Comment: Thanks this is what I have got similar type of answer from Alexandre Dutra from datastax community - https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/d/msg/java-driver-user/TKrpwfXSF_0/ntEMorQWCAAJ

Comment: Yes, I’ve seen it after I posted the answer. But that’s expected as this is a thing that we see by customers